# How do we prove that the following implication in semiring?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, semirings

Let $G$ be a group. Clearly the power set $(\mathcal{P}(G),\cup,. )$ is the semiring, where $\cup$ means ordinary union and '.' is defined as $$AB= \left\lbrace ab \in G \mid a\in A\mbox{ and } b\in B \right\rbrace,\qquad \forall A, B \subseteq G.$$ Also we define $$A^{-1}=\lbrace a^{-1}\in G \mid a \in G \rbrace, \quad\bar{A}= G \smallsetminus A^{-1},\qquad \forall A \subseteq G.$$ Question:

> How do we prove that the following implication ($B,C,D\subseteq G$):
>   $$BC \subseteq D\quad\Rightarrow\quad\bar{D}B  \subseteq \bar{C}\quad?$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $d\in \overline{D}$ and $b\in B$ are such that $db\in C^{-1}$; then there exists $c\in C$ such that $db=c^{-1}$. Right-multiplying by $c$ you get $d(bc)=e$. But $bc\in BC\subseteq D$, and therefore $d=(bc)^{-1}\in D^{-1}$, contradicting the choice of $d$.

Therefore, if $d\in\overline{D}$ and $b\in B$, then $db\notin C^{-1}$; that is, $db\in \overline{C}$, as desired.